# How do you represent all of the parameters (names & values) contained in a HttpServletRequest object as a single string?

Tags: java, string, http-request-parameters

Is there some way to get all of the parameters contained in a [**HttpServletRequest**](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) object into a single String?

Answer (score 1):

```
request.getQueryString(); // To get into a single string
request.getParameterMap(); // to get into a map of key-value pairs
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of frameworks that will do this sort of thing for you. It depends a lot on what technologies you are employing. Personally I prefer [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) for the simple reasons that it emcompasses pretty much everything I've needed to do. The only downside is that there's a lot to learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

This at first sight simple problem is complicated by the fact that getParameterMap() returns a `Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]>`, so attempts to `toString()` the return value don't give the desired result.

In case you would need the parameters as a JSON string anyways, or don't mind an extra dependency, this is a very simple solution using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/):

```
String asJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(request.getParameterMap());
```

for

```
parm1=abc&parm=cde&parm3=fgh&parm3=ijk
```

it produces

```
{"parm1":["abc"],"parm":["cde"],"parm3":["fgh","ijk"]}
```

Comment: why wouldn't request.getQueryString() work? THat is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @rational it works, depending on what OP wants to do with the output string it may very well be sufficient.  I just wanted to point out an alternative solution with some extra capabilities, like json structured output and grouped representation of parameters that occur more than once.